# How to refresh an already opened web page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, refresh

I just want to refresh an already opened web page with `Selenium`.

It always opens a new browser window.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
import urllib2

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `driver.navigate().refresh()`?

Comment: The code you show does not reproduce the problem you are reporting. The line `webdriver.Frirefox()` will start a new browser. But `driver.refresh()` does not do anything with the code you show. If you add a `driver.get()` call to load a good URL, then the page refreshes as it should.

Answer (score 53):

I would suggest binding the driver element search to the tag body and use the refresh command of the browser.

In OSX for example

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'r')
```

Documentation on keys here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

Update:
The following code, very similar to your one, works fine for me.

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(response.url) #tested in combination with scrapy   
    time.sleep(3)   
    driver.refresh()
```

Are you sure you correctly load the web page with the driver before refreshing it ?

Comment: Even in OSX, `driver.refresh()` works good. The first one with CMD + r didn't.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is you are opening the webdriver and then trying to refresh when you have not specified a URL.

All you need to do is get your desired URL before refreshing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
import urllib2
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("Your desired URL goes here...")
#now you can refresh the page!
driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 4):

The following codes work for me

```
driver.get(driver.current_url)
sleep(2)
driver.refresh()
```

I use python 3.7.6, selenium 3.141.0

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to refresh the page before it loads so u can use a sleep function

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
```

or you can wait for an XPath to load so

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath goes here)))
```

Answer (score 1):

For me helped

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("URL")

time.sleep(5)
driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try any one of the below methods for the same.

Method 1:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("s")).sendKeys(Keys.F5);
```

Method 2:

```
driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Method3:

```
driver.navigate().to(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Method4:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("s")).sendKeys("\uE035");
```

Comment: This does not pertain to python, which is the language tagged

Comment: That's not python

Answer (score -1):

I got mine fixed by adding "`browser.refresh()`" the for loop or while loop.