# Which code I could use to refresh an website using R?

Tags: r, powerbi, refresh

I'm trying to refresh an Power BI dashboard to capture new data I **scrape** every hour.

I've tried `shell.exec("link")` in R to refresh it but it opened a new window. I´d like only to refresh it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows, one can refresh a page using Shift+F5.

```
cls <- function () { 
  require(RDCOMClient) 
  wsh <- COMCreate("Wscript.Shell") 
  wsh$SendKeys("+{F5}") 
  invisible(wsh) 
} 
cls()
```

For more keypresses [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/8c6yea83(v=vs.84)).

---

### Edit - 1 Nov 2019

The problem with the approach mentioned above is that

> how do I know which window is active?

, which I could not answer using R.

Instead I suggest a different take using [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html) with methods *navigate* and *refresh*

```
remDr$navigate("https://...")
remDr$refresh()
```

If you decide to call a Python or JavaScript script from R to do the dirty work for you, then have a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10245641/5675325) which is quite similar to yours and most answers use it to refresh.

Comment: ok, but I need to refresh an website in chrome

Comment: For Windows and Linux: Shift+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: Using R, not with the keyboard.

Comment: Other workaround is to call a Python script inside R (invoking a [system command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638674/5675325)). Then, inside the Python script you use `SendKeys`.

Comment: Ok, But how do I know which windows is active?

Comment: Right... Was doing some research and the solution to the problem might pass through using [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28457515/5675325). ([For inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26905716/5675325).)

Comment: Using [RSelenium](https://rpubs.com/johndharrison/14707), `remDr$navigate("https://...")
remDr$refresh()`

Comment: [This link explains better](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html).

Comment: Thanks, rselenium its a good choice!

Comment: Awesome, glad i could help @Brun Ijbh.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark as answer.